# /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied when installing Postgres

Tags: bash, centos, permissions

I have already looked at similar posts in this forum related to bad interpreter and denied permissions, and was unable to find a solution to this problem.

I have a vps Linux x64 (v2.6.18; CentOS 6.7). I am working on a particular project (OpenClinica) for a client and I need to install Postgresql version 8.4 (old version, I know) directly from a .bin file. The file looks like `postgresql-8.4.1-1-linux-x64.bin`. As far as I understood, this `.bin` file creates some `.sh` files on `/tmp/postgresql_installer/`.

I was also told that this file works OK and has already successfully performed installations of Postgres on many other Linux (CentOS) systems running OpenClinica.

When I run it as root at the command line typing this

```
./postgresql* --mode text
```

I get the frustrating message below.

```
Error: 
Error running /tmp/postgresql_installer/getlocales.sh  : 
/bin/sh: /tmp/postgresql_installer/getlocales.sh: 
/bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

What I have already checked (looking in this and other forums)

1. the first line of `getlocales.sh` has `#!/bin/sh` in it
2. there is a link `sh -> bash*` at `/bin`

   ```
   root@vps [/bin]# ls -l sh
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Nov 14 12:29 sh -> bash*
   ```
3. `sestatus` is DISABLED
4. I gave `chmod x` permission to `postgres*.bin` before I ran it.
5. I have even tried to run `postgres*.bin` from `~/` with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you forbidden executables files in the /tmp dir?

Comment: What do you get from `echo postgresql*` in the directory you are running it from?

Comment: please show output of `sed -n 1l /tmp/postgresql_installer/getlocales.sh` - does that end with `\r$`?  was the script edited or created on a windows machine?

Comment: That would result into "No such file or directory". I just remounted noexec my /tmp and it also ends up with "Permission denied" when trying to run scripts from it. Perhaps OP has same setup.

Comment: To @RuiFRibeiro: in /tmp/postgresql_installer there are only 3 .sh files and all have x permission.

Comment: To @JeffSchaller: 'echo postgresql*' just returns the name of the .bin file, i.e., 'postgresql-8.4.1-1-linus-x64.bin'

Comment: To @cas: I've downloaded the .bin file from OpenClinica repo, and as far as I know, it was NOT edited or created in a Windows machine. I was informed that this file worked before on Linux machines. The output of the sed command follows:
.sh 
#!/bin/sh$

Comment: It is not about the files having the x permission is about /tmp being mounted with noexec.

Comment: To rui's point, what is the output of `mount|grep /tmp `?

Comment: RESOLVED!! Thank you all. All comments helped me in the right direction and made think about it... SOLUTION: My system had (for some reason) a NOEXEC flag set at /etc/fstab. I changed it to 'defaults' and it worked. Many thanks!!

Comment: Rui, muito obrigado!!

Comment: I would also like to thank @Jakuje for correcting and formatting my question.

Comment: De nada. I actually posted the answer, with some explanation why this happens.

Answer (score 4):

As said, the problem was having /tmp mounted with noexec. The explanation is quite simple, some install scripts uncompress executables/scripts at /tmp and then try to run them.

I actually stumbled on this problem too by chance some moons ago, when I changed in a couple of servers /tmp to be noexec for security reasons, and then the install/update scripts of some Debian packages stopped working. As I had changed it on purpose it was quite easy to identify the problem at the time.

I still think it is a good idea to set /tmp to noexec in public webservers, however until now I have not researched much how to get around this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Rui's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/243213/117549), I executed the below-mentioned command; it works for me.

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```